# How load nested Response JSON into a dataframe without saving in a file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe, api

I'm attempting to load a pandas a dataframe with a heavily nesting JSON. This JSON is the result of an API code in Python. Here is the structure of the JSON file:

```
{
    'results': [{
            'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'id': '6ed909bd16',
            'partition': None,
            'externalId': None,
            'metadata': None,
            'name': 'NewSeptemberFile20220908',
            'description': None,
            'created': '2022-09-12T22:04:55.799+00:00',
            'lastModified': '2022-09-12T22:06:10.838+00:00',
            'lastIndexed': '2022-09-12T22:05:04.551+00:00',
            'privacyMode': 'Private',
            'userName': 'M M',
            'isOwned': True,
            'isBase': True,
            'hasSourceVideoFile': True,
            'state': 'Processed',
            'moderationState': 'OK',
            'reviewState': 'None',
            'processingProgress': '100%',
            'durationInSeconds': 58,
            'thumbnailVideoId': '6ed909bd16',
            'thumbnailId': '5f04af4d-e382-4387-9573-6d9e4bad3b68',
            'searchMatches': [],
            'indexingPreset': 'Default',
            'streamingPreset': 'Default',
            'sourceLanguage': 'en-GB',
            'sourceLanguages': ['en-GB'],
            'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        }, {
            'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'id': '34344818e8',
            'partition': None,
            'externalId': None,
            'metadata': None,
            'name': '3September',
            'description': None,
            'created': '2022-09-09T17:55:59.696+00:00',
            'lastModified': '2022-09-09T17:57:51.057+00:00',
            'lastIndexed': '2022-09-09T17:56:04.544+00:00',
            'privacyMode': 'Private',
            'userName': 'M M',
            'isOwned': True,
            'isBase': True,
            'hasSourceVideoFile': True,
            'state': 'Processed',
            'moderationState': 'OK',
            'reviewState': 'None',
            'processingProgress': '100%',
            'durationInSeconds': 58,
            'thumbnailVideoId': '34344818e8',
            'thumbnailId': 'baae7ed1-a791-4481-853c-1707b40b5e77',
            'searchMatches': [],
            'indexingPreset': 'Default',
            'streamingPreset': 'Default',
            'sourceLanguage': 'en-GB',
            'sourceLanguages': ['en-GB'],
            'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        }, {
            'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'id': '82da4b60ef',
            'partition': None,
            'externalId': None,
            'metadata': None,
            'name': 'film10',
            'description': None,
            'created': '2022-08-22T14:24:08.442+00:00',
            'lastModified': '2022-09-08T23:13:16.416+00:00',
            'lastIndexed': '2022-08-22T14:24:12.605+00:00',
            'privacyMode': 'Private',
            'userName': 'M M',
            'isOwned': True,
            'isBase': True,
            'hasSourceVideoFile': True,
            'state': 'Processed',
            'moderationState': 'OK',
            'reviewState': 'None',
            'processingProgress': '100%',
            'durationInSeconds': 58,
            'thumbnailVideoId': '82da4b60ef',
            'thumbnailId': '5a5f6a71-0302-46a6-93c8-beb918c00b14',
            'searchMatches': [],
            'indexingPreset': 'Default',
            'streamingPreset': 'Default',
            'sourceLanguage': 'en-GB',
            'sourceLanguages': ['en-GB'],
            'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        }, {
            'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'id': '7ea0c5e34a',
            'partition': None,
            'externalId': None,
            'metadata': None,
            'name': 'davide_quatela--people_in_frankfurt',
            'description': None,
            'created': '2022-09-07T21:31:52.818+00:00',
            'lastModified': '2022-09-08T22:52:52.833+00:00',
            'lastIndexed': '2022-09-07T21:31:57.328+00:00',
            'privacyMode': 'Private',
            'userName': 'M M',
            'isOwned': True,
            'isBase': True,
            'hasSourceVideoFile': True,
            'state': 'Processed',
            'moderationState': 'OK',
            'reviewState': 'None',
            'processingProgress': '100%',
            'durationInSeconds': 131,
            'thumbnailVideoId': '7ea0c5e34a',
            'thumbnailId': '3aba8f42-a3a7-4d77-92b0-8cabcc275a3b',
            'searchMatches': [],
            'indexingPreset': 'Default',
            'streamingPreset': 'Default',
            'sourceLanguage': 'en-US',
            'sourceLanguages': ['en-US'],
            'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        }, {
            'accountId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'id': '7c45ae7ffe',
            'partition': None,
            'externalId': None,
            'metadata': None,
            'name': 'Untitled project',
            'description': None,
            'created': '2022-08-17T17:36:23.72+00:00',
            'lastModified': '2022-08-17T17:36:49.95+00:00',
            'lastIndexed': '2022-08-17T17:36:49.95+00:00',
            'privacyMode': 'Private',
            'userName': 'M M',
            'isOwned': True,
            'isBase': False,
            'hasSourceVideoFile': False,
            'state': 'Processed',
            'moderationState': 'OK',
            'reviewState': 'None',
            'processingProgress': '',
            'durationInSeconds': 0,
            'thumbnailVideoId': None,
            'thumbnailId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
            'searchMatches': [],
            'indexingPreset': None,
            'streamingPreset': 'Default',
            'sourceLanguage': 'en-US',
            'sourceLanguages': ['en-US'],
            'personModelId': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        }
    ],
    'nextPage': {
        'pageSize': 25,
        'skip': 0,
        'done': True
    }
}
```

And this is my code in Python 3.x:

```
url = "https://api.videoindexer.ai/" + Location + "/Accounts/" + AzVIAccountID + "/Videos?pageSize=25&skip=0&accessToken=" + iAccessToken

    response = requests.get(url,headers=hdr )
    ### Response: 200 OK
    print("If Response=200 Script run is OK : " , response.status_code)
```

I want the result to be like this:[image]

**Question:** Is there a possibility to fetch 'name', 'id', and 'create' of all videos which are showing in the JSON result (Response API) into a dataframe directly?

Answer (score 0):

If `data` contains the data from the question you can do:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])

columns_i_want = ["id", "name", "created"]
df = df[columns_i_want]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           id                                 name                        created
0  6ed909bd16             NewSeptemberFile20220908  2022-09-12T22:04:55.799+00:00
1  34344818e8                           3September  2022-09-09T17:55:59.696+00:00
2  82da4b60ef                               film10  2022-08-22T14:24:08.442+00:00
3  7ea0c5e34a  davide_quatela--people_in_frankfurt  2022-09-07T21:31:52.818+00:00
4  7c45ae7ffe                     Untitled project   2022-08-17T17:36:23.72+00:00
```

---

EDIT:

```py
url = (
    "https://api.videoindexer.ai/"
    + Location
    + "/Accounts/"
    + AzVIAccountID
    + "/Videos?pageSize=25&skip=0&accessToken="
    + iAccessToken
)
response = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
data = response.json()
# make sure the correct response is sent:
print(data)

# if above command prints correct data, you can do next:
df = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])
columns_i_want = ["id", "name", "created"]
df = df[columns_i_want]

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, what is data int the first line? I can make a dataframe when I save it into a file and then load the file to a dataframe; but is there possibility to save a JSON response directly to the dataframe ?

Comment: @mnn The `data` can be obtained for example with `data = requests.get(url,headers=hdr).json()` You generally don't want to save JSON strings in the dataframe.

Comment: I've tried it but got error: _TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable _ so I've tried to fix this error with _data = response.json()
    print(response["id"])_ but got the same error again. any clue?

Comment: @mnn See my edit.